# try to build dial number by React

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, numbers, picker

Hi I'm trying to build a component.

This is not a react-native. I'm want to use react and scroll a number like a picture

[image: ios picker]

It should roll the number.

I was trying to find an example but there was an only react-native example.
(link : [How do I make an iOS UIPicker in react native with multiple columns and titles?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55581912/how-do-i-make-an-ios-uipicker-in-react-native-with-multiple-columns-and-titles))

Is there React example????

Comment: Do you need something like this? 

Here's multiple react packages. 

https://github.com/lanjingling0510/react-mobile-datepicker#readme
https://github.com/swenyang/react-date-picker

Examples
https://codepen.io/lanjingling0510/pen/LRpOYp?editors=1010
https://swenyang.github.io/react-date-picker/

Answer (score 1):

You can possibly use [react-mobile-datepicker](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-mobile-datepicker) package.

Here's a working example at [Codesanbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-ios-style-datepicker-uipicker-u8h04?file=/src/App.js:85-108).

```js
import React from "react";
import DatePicker from "react-mobile-datepicker";

class App extends React.Component {
  state = {
    time: new Date(),
    isOpen: false
  };

  handleClick = () => {
    this.setState({ isOpen: true });
  };

  handleCancel = () => {
    this.setState({ isOpen: false });
  };

  handleSelect = (time) => {
    this.setState({ time, isOpen: false });
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <a className="select-btn" onClick={this.handleClick}>
          select time
        </a>

        <DatePicker
          value={this.state.time}
          isOpen={this.state.isOpen}
          onSelect={this.handleSelect}
          onCancel={this.handleCancel}
        />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```